# Releasing IBOutlets in UIViewController’s viewDidUnload?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, nib, ios

I’m a bit confused as to what happens exactly in Nib-based `UIViewController`s. When generating a `UIViewController` subclass, the template contains a very specific comment in the `viewDidUnload` method:

```
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
```

Which subviews does this apply to?

- The ones I initialized in `viewDidLoad`? (I’d say yes)
- The ones I initialized in `initWithNibName`? (I’d say no)
- The `IBOutlet`s that reference objects in the Nib?

If I use the view controller like this:

```
MyViewController *controller = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

In this case I suppose it doesn’t matter much whether instance variables that hold references to subview are released in `viewDidUnload` or `dealloc` since `dealloc` should get called as soon as the view controller is popped off the stack so I might as well do as Apple says and release instance variables on `viewDidUnload` instead of `dealloc`.

But suppose I used `MyViewController` as an instance variable that may be pushed multiple times:

```
if(self.myViewController == nil) {
    self.myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:nil];
}
// Change some state which should be reflected in the view
self.myViewController.someProperty = someValue;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.myViewController animated:YES];
```

What happens in `MyViewController` if I release an `IBOutlet` in `viewDidUnload`? Can I count on having a new reference to it on the next `viewDidLoad`?

In other words: what happens to the view itself after `viewDidUnload`? Is it released and re-loaded from the Nib if the controller is pushed again? Or does the view remain in memory? And if so, do the outlets get re-set before `viewDidLoad`?

If either the view remains in memory and the outlets are re-set before `viewDidLoad` (or is reloaded each time the controller is pushed), I suppose it would be correct to release the outlets in `viewDidUnload` (even though in the first case it does not matter). But otherwise (specifically if the view remains in memory and the outlets are NOT re-set), releasing the subviews in `viewDidUnload` is wrong for the use case I presented, am I correct?

Comment: Update: Note that `viewDidUnload` will be deprecated for iOS 6 because, apparently, it was confusing to a lot of developers (not just me) and they were quite often using it wrong in a way, which would cause their app to crash/misbehave when memory warnings occurred at times that developers didn’t account for…

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [UIViewController documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), Memory Management section:

> When a low-memory warning occurs, the `UIViewController` class purges its views if it knows it can reload or recreate them again later. If this happens, it also calls the `viewDidUnload` method to give your code a chance to relinquish ownership of any objects that are associated with your view hierarchy, including objects loaded with the nib file, objects created in your `viewDidLoad` method, and objects created lazily at runtime and added to the view hierarchy. Typically, if your view controller contains outlets (properties or raw variables that contain the `IBOutlet` keyword), you should use the `viewDidUnload` method to relinquish ownership of those outlets or any other view-related data that you no longer need.

So not only can you release your outlets in `viewDidUnload`, this is the preferred and recommended way.

And yes, you can count on having your outlets point to valid objects when `viewDidLoad` is called. Again from the UIViewController documentation, on `viewDidLoad`:

> This method is called after the view controller has loaded its associated views into memory.

Comment: Just to make sure: If one adds additional views in viewDidLoad:, it is essential to remove and release them in viewDidUnload:, because it may well be that viewDidLoad: will get called later a second time and I'd be left with multiple copies of the additional subviews?

Comment: First of all, you should really do all your memory management through properties, and not access ivars directly. To answer your question, even if you use properties and release in dealloc (and therefore not cause a memory leak), there's still no point in keeping them around since they will be recreated in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Following your guidance, I should make all retained objects properties, and thereby loose the concept of private variables, correct?

Comment: @afEkenholm: private and property are not necessarily mutually exclusive, you can have private properties.